# how to select the last 4 elements using nth child?

Tags: jquery, css, sass, css-selectors

I am wanting to select the last 4 elements using nth-child. Is there a way of doing this?

I am not able to add unique classes to these children so I need a way to be able to identify which are the last 4 children so that I can edit these whilst not affecting the others?

I am using Advanced custom fields for Wordpress so my code looks like this:

```
<div class="all-skills-div">
            <?php
                if( have_rows('skills') ):
                while( have_rows('skills') ):
                the_row();
            ?>
                <div class="single-skill-div">
                   <?php echo the_sub_field('a_skill'); ?>
                </div>
            <?php 
                endwhile;
                endif;
            ?>
</div>
```

The subfield is outputting about 9 different lines of text (right now but this could change due to it being dynamic)  so I want to target the last 4.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it:

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;;
}

ul li:nth-last-child(-n+4) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>  
  <li>2</li>  
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>  
  <li>5</li>  
  <li>6</li>  
  <li>7</li>  
  <li>8</li>  
  <li>9</li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: Please provide you HTML and CSS code or jsfiddle. So, I can help you.

Comment: I've got it working now thanks to your suggestion! Thanks so much. I wasn't able to find what I was looking for on Google when looking :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use nth-last-child - [nth generator](http://www.topdesignagencies.com/nth-test/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this,

```
$('#something a:nth-last-child(-n+4)').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use CSS `#something:nth-last-child(-n+4)` for last four subfields.